# Distribution for Response Times

Tags: statistics

I have samples from a response time population for a web transaction. I want to be able to use them to describe a distribution for the population but don't know a proper one to use. I have shied away from a Normal since it would result in some probability of getting a negative time. Could someone suggest a reasonable approach?

Please go easy with the responses; I'm an engineer, not a math guy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try fitting a [log-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution). If you have more interesting data, it's possible that some sort of power-law distribution would fit better. See, for instance, the [Lévy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levy_distribution).

Comment: log-normal seems reasonable. Looking at the Wikipedia article, I like the long tail which is what I typically see. So I have my app server log with 1 day's worth of response times (~800k samples). How do I determine sigma and mu to get my CDF from the wiki provided equation?

Comment: For mu I found the 50% (.024) of my data and set that equal to e^mu and solved for mu. Is that wrong for mu (-3.73)?

Comment: If we are assuming that your response time data is log-normal, then the $\mu$ you want is really just the mean of the response times. Then you would try to adjust $\sigma$ so that the PDF matches your observed distribution. You can use nonlinear fitting software, such as `nlinfit` in MATLAB, or do it by hand using trial and error.

Comment: In the end, looks like my data doesn't follow a distribution model. Used a KS test to check and it is borderline/failing. I think the problem is that my data is effectively discrete since the response times are measured to the ms. Too big a bucket. Might also have to divide up transactions by type. Regardless, I did like using the log-normal model and found it easiest to work with when I converted to the ln domain since then I could assume normal and thus use all the tools available for a normal distribution. Thanks for the help.